# Error ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Tags: oracle-spatial

I am running this SQL in Oracle Spatial in postgis worked. 
In the Oracle error

`[Err] ORA-00920: invalid relational operator`

I need to select all geometries that touch on my streets layer, ie the corners.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (b.cdidelog) AS Cruzamento
FROM
    "GIVVI_EIXO_LOGR" A,
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            "GIVVI_EIXO_LOGR"
    ) b
WHERE
    ST_Touches (A.geom, b.geom)
AND A.cdlog = 7775026
AND A.nmidelog <> b.nmidelog
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Names of spatial operators are not the same in Oracle. SDO_TOUCH or SDO_RELATE with 'mask=TOUCH' should work http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_operat.htm#BGEHHIGF.